# Belief In God or Knowledge Of God. Which is better?

Tags: gods, belief

A lot of people in the society believe in God, but barely have knowledge of God. Does God help them? 
Belief is better or knowledge of God? Or belief after knowledge of God?

The question arises:

1. Will god help people who don't have knowledge about God but believe in God?
2. Will God accept people who worship God according to their own faith/beliefs?
3. Can a person deny a knowledge written in religious books and begin worshiping god according to his own understanding. Will god help them?

Comment: God and his knowledge are non different!!! He shows himself to you based on what manner you approach!

Comment: You are indirectly asking, which is better Bhakti marga, or Gyan marga.

Comment: Knowledge comes after acting on beliefs, thus Knowledge of God is better than belief of God.

Comment: Please go through the story of Kannapa, you'll surely get some answers there. All the best.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **Will god help people who don't have knowledge about God but Believe in God?**

Yes of course.Sri Krishna says in the Gita :

> 10.11 Out of compassion for them alone, I, residing in their hearts, destroy the darkness born of ignorance with the luminous lamp of Knowledge.

So God Himself will reveal the True Knowledge to them.

2. **Will God accept people who worship God according to their own faith/beliefs?**

Yes. Sri Krishna says in the Gita:

> 4.11 According to the manner in which they approach Me, I favour them in that very manner. O son of Partha, human beings follow My path in every way.

3. **Can a person deny a knowledge written in Religious books and begin worshiping god according to his own understanding. Will god help them?**

   No. Sri Krishna says in the Gita:

> 16.23 Ignoring the precept of the scriptures, he who acts under the impulsion of passion,-he does not attain perfection, nor happiness, nor the supreme Goal.
>
> 16.24 Therefore, the scripture is your authority as regards the determination of what is to be done and what is not to be done. After understanding (your) duty as presented by scriptural injunction, you ought to perform (your duty) here.

Hope these answers your queries.

Answer (score 1):

The **Ramcharitmanas** by Tulsidas Pandit in Uttar-Kand (Kaak Bhushundi and Garud samvad) says it clearly,

> "jane binu na hohahi partiti, binu partiti na hohahi preeti; preeti bina na bhakti dridahahi, jimi khagpati jal kai chiknayi."

It is said that the devotion becomes strengthened with the knowledge because by knowing someone the affinity in the relationship enhances.

Nevertheless, in the case of the divine gopis (uneducated cowherd girl children), their knowledge about eternity becomes immaterial because of their unconditional transcendental love for Krishna. Our consciousness is not like that of divine gopis. So, the knowledge about God is also always advisable.[image]

Comment: The Goois were fully aware of Sri Krishna's Divinity as per Srimad-Bhagavatam.

Comment: that might be the reason they worshipped goddess katyayni to grant them krishna as their husband.  good citation !!

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: They said to Krishna: You are NOT a cowherd boy,You reside as Antaratma in every being.This is a famous sloka of Srimad-Bhagavatam.

Comment: The Gopi-geet is a song of love for krishna sung by devotees (gopis) at supreme exalted position in devotion when they had already participated in the childhood pastimes with krishna.